# Relation between Operation, Payemnt and Effect

Tags: transactions, payments, operations

What is the relation between “Operation of type: payment”, “Payment” and “Effect of type: account_credited”?

Can “Payment operation” be submitted and not results in “Effect” (e.g. because of insufficient funds)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Payment** is actually a result of the **successful** execution of a [**payment operation**](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/operation.html#payment). A successful payment operation will yield two [**effects**](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/effect.html#effect-types) (Account Credited and Account Debited).

If a transaction fails it yields no effects, and won't be displayed in [payment API endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/payments-all.html).

Comment: Can I verify somewhere in the documentation? When I query transactions, do I see all transactions (verified and unverified)?  Is it possible the transaction will be roll backed for some reason even after I made query which returned such transaction?

Comment: A transaction is executed as a [single unit of work](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#life-cycle). If any operation included into a transaction fails, the whole transaction fails, and the effects of previous operations in that transaction are rolled back. When you query the Horizon API, you see only applied transactions. Failed transactions are never shown because they are not included in the ledger.

Answer (score 1):

A transaction is a group of one or more operations being sent to the Stellar network to all succeed or all fail together.

An operation is a command to the Stellar Network.  This can be create account, send a payment, make an offer (to exchange asset for asset), change account settings, etc.

A payment is a transaction that includes a payment operation.  The payment operation transfers the amount you want to send of the asset you want to send to the destination account.

All of the effects are API endpoints that let you see the history of operations applied to an account.  The Effect of Type: Account Credited, is an endpoint where you can monitor incoming payments to an account.